# How to convert getRecordUi to Page Layout on LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, page-layout, lwc-wire-adapter

**tl;dr** - How do I turn the page layout info returned from getRecordUi into an end-user-friendly page-layout in an LWC?

**Background:**

I am trying to create a complete copy of a record's page layout in an LWC. After researching the [getRecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) adapter, it appears that it is possible to capture all of the page layout's information. However, I cannot find any instruction on how to turn the getRecordUi's returned data into something like a lighting-record-edit-form.

Using the Salesforce's documentation code (posted below) as an example, I have successfully acquired accountRecordUI, but don't know how to turn the data in accountRecordUI into a record-editing interface that mirrors that of the account's standard page layout.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecordUi } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getRecordUi, { recordIds: '001456789012345678', layoutTypes: 'Full', modes: 'View' })
  accountRecordUi;
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: If you debug the returned value, you'll see the full information you get back ;)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer Yes, accessing the return value isn't the issue. It's how to use the info to create a page-layout

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, are you asking for somebody to write this for you or did you face difficulties and are trying to overcome them?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I'm trying to get pointed in a direction for what appears to be a gap in the documentation. The [getRecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) documentation ends abruptly at the point of returning a record's data and metadata, but doesn't say how to put this data to use. I need help in finding the gap in instruction between the returned metadata and creating a user-facing page layout.

Comment: Your first step should be to output to console the object returned.

Comment: @Jwok did you work this out? I would also like to display the ui parts.

Comment: @hgolov I was not unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

I've recorded the responses to getRecordUi for both [Full View](https://gist.github.com/bluehrs/560be5bb9e8021e2e26acc232a51f4d9) and [Full Edit](https://gist.github.com/bluehrs/4494876f1e761ecd047e4224f7a3ce8a). They're both super dense, but was able to get them to display properly with `lightning-record-edit-form`, `lightning-output-field`, and `lightning-input-field` through some nested loops.

Controller:

```
uiRecordView;
uiRecordEdit;

@wire(getRecordUi, {
        recordIds: "$recordId",
        layoutTypes: "Full",
        modes: "View",
    })
    wiredRecordView({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            for (let layout of Object.values(data.layouts.User)) {
                this.uiRecordView = layout.Full.View;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // TODO: Data handling
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecordUi, {
        recordIds: "$recordId",
        layoutTypes: "Full",
        modes: "Edit",
    })
    wiredRecordEdit({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            for (let layout of Object.values(data.layouts.User)) {
                this.uiRecordEdit = layout.Full.Edit;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // TODO: Data handling
        }
    }
```

Component:

```
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open="true" active-section-name={activeSectionNames}>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
      record-id={recordId}
      object-api-name="User"
      onsuccess={handleSuccess}
      onerror={handleError}>
      <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

      <template if:true={uiRecordView}>
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
          <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <template for:each={uiRecordView.sections} for:item="section">
              <lightning-accordion-section key={section.id} name={section.id} label={section.heading}>
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                  <template for:each={section.layoutRows} for:item="layoutRow">
                    <template for:each={layoutRow.layoutItems} for:item="layoutItem">
                      <template for:each={layoutItem.layoutComponents} for:item="layoutComponent">
                        <lightning-layout-item key={layoutComponent.apiName} size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                          <template if:false={editable}>
                            <lightning-output-field
                              field-name={layoutComponent.apiName}>
                            </lightning-output-field>
                          </template>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                  </template>
                </lightning-layout>
              </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
      </template>

      <template if:true={uiRecordEdit}>
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
          <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <template for:each={uiRecordEdit.sections} for:item="section">
              <lightning-accordion-section key={section.id} name={section.id} label={section.heading}>
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                  <template for:each={section.layoutRows} for:item="layoutRow">
                    <template for:each={layoutRow.layoutItems} for:item="layoutItem">
                      <template for:each={layoutItem.layoutComponents} for:item="layoutComponent">
                        <lightning-layout-item key={layoutComponent.apiName} size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                          <template if:false={editable}>
                            <lightning-input-field
                              field-name={layoutComponent.apiName}
                              required={layoutItem.required}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                          </template>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                  </template>
                </lightning-layout>
              </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
      </template>

    </lightning-record-edit-form>
  </<lightning-accordion>
```